# Propaganistas / Laravel-Phone, how to only accept international format (E.164) for a specific country?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I want to accept international phone number format for only numbers from UAE, using the Propaganistas / Laravel-Phone package.

I tried using the below code snippet, but it allows any international phone number + local phone number from AE.

```
'phonefield' => 'phone:INTERNATIONAL,AE',
```

So with this, it accepts all countries' phone numbers in international format + it will also accept local phone numbers from UAE. However, I want to only accept international format of UAE numbers, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I did this, is this right by any chance? It seems to work.

```
$input_phone = $data['username'];
$phone = new PhoneNumber($input_phone);

if (!$phone->isValid() || !$phone->isOfCountry('AE'))
    return response()->error(null, __('validation.phone', ['attribute' => 'phone']), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

$data['username'] = $phone->formatE164();
```

Comment: Your answer is asking more questions, edit your question instead.